# Play Framework: How to change play default packages?

Tags: java, playframework

I was just wondering if it is possible to change the default packages from Play. For example: I want to change the "controllers" package to "com.test.controllers". I don't know if this makes any sense, but I just want to know how if it is possible. I did not find anything related to this in play website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Updated to make the distinction between play1 and 2 clear.*

**For Play 1.x, this is not possible.**

No, all controllers must be in a package, or sub package of controllers.
If you wanted to keep a `com.test` package structure, you can do `controllers.com.test`

For more info, [see this thread.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!searchin/play-framework/package$20structure/play-framework/5whJqqla8mM/L8u4kaItKksJ)

**For Play2.x, this is possible.** Just move everything to the package you desire. Make sure that the outermost `app/` directory stays at outside. An example would be `play-project/app/com.company/controllers`.

So the simple answer is...it depends, on whst version of Play you are using.

Comment: No longer the case, as noted in other answers (just in case people get the wrong idea).

Comment: not quite that simple. Play 2 indeed does allow this, but current versions of Play 1. I make the distinction because Play 1 and Play 2 are very different frameworks, and it isn't a simple upgrade path.

Answer (score 21):

According to the [current](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/Anatomy) Play 2.0 documentation, this is now possible:

> Note that in Play 2.0, the controllers, models and views package name conventions are now just that and can be changed if needed (such as prefixing everything with com.yourcompany).

This works well for an empty Play application, there are however some details to take note of for anything else:

1. Importing custom namespaces into view templates will work for any types except for those that are declared in the first line of a template, which are the arguments for the scala *render* function that is generated out of a view. Our workaround is to add the full package name to type declarations in the first line of view templates.
2. For every namespace defined in the routes file (e.g. a custom package and the default package for the Assets route), Play 2.0 generates a corresponding routes source file within the same namespace, so you need to take care to address the correct file when e.g. doing redirection.

Comment: I had some trouble understanding point 2 - assuming we move from the default package to package foo.bar then it means any remote routes in the views need to change from routes.Application.method to foo.bar.controllers.Application.method.

Comment: Let's say you have a controller MyController with a handler method called myMethod. If you move it from the "controllers" package to "com.example.controllers", you have to (1) in your Scala templates, change @routes.MyController.myMethod() to @com.example.controllers.routes.MyController.myMethod() and (2) in your controller class itself, change any redirects that it makes (e.g. after POSTing a form) from controllers.routes.MyController.someMethod() to com.example.controllers.routes.MyController.someMethod().

Comment: So I'm on 2.4.x - how do I go about prefixing the package with com.yourcompany. I have my `app`, `conf`, `public` and `test` under `com/yourcompany` but sbt doesn't seem to compile any .java files inside those folders. I cannot seem to find any doc around this.

Comment: @ronaldwidha, you've probably figured this out now, but if you want to namespace your views, for example, create a directory: apps/com/yourcompany/views, and then refer to views like com.yourcompany.views.

Answer (score 13):

From the [manual](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/routes):

> A Controller class must be defined in
>   the **controllers** package and must
>   be a subclass of
>   **play.mvc.Controller**.
>
> You can add a Java package before the
>   Controller class name if it isn’t
>   defined directly under the controllers
>   package. The **controllers** package
>   itself is implicit, so you don’t need
>   to specify it.

This means that you can't change your `controllers` package to `com.test.controllers` (because the root package must be `controllers`), but you can change to `controllers.com.test`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a discussion of this [here](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_frm/thread/e70849aaa95af263/e8f6bc1ce743430c?lnk=gst&q=package#e8f6bc1ce743430c).

Also there is [this](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1.1/faq#aWhydontyourenametheplaypackagetoorg.playframeworka) in the FAQ.

Comment: Please add descriptions instead of only links. Links rot. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144566/new-policy-on-link-only-answers

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but for people who can encounter the same situation in 2022, This is possible with Play 2.8.x [Scala doc, but is valid for Java too](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaRouting).

You can define your custom package **com.test.controllers** (even in the root **App** folder).
You need after to define routes for it classes to match **Reverse routing** as stated in the documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaRouting#Reverse-routing).

For example, if you defined a class **foo.java** that has a method **index** that is accessible at endpoint **/index**,  your routes file have to reflect it like this:

```
GET /index  com.test.controllers.foo.index
```

And you can access it from the HTML file using helper (Reverse routing) like this:

```
@com.test.controllers.routes.foo.index()
```