# PlayFramework 2.1, submodules and Eclipse having errors about invalid package name

Tags: eclipse, playframework-2.1

Using PlayFramework 2.1 and submodules, I have an error with all my controllers in Eclipse :

> "The declared package "controllers.website" does not match the expected package "controllers"

Of course, because in my module, I added controllers in `modules/{submodule_name}/app/controllers/`, eg: `modules/website/app/controllers/`

But as defined in the documentation of Play, controllers must have the package name "controllers.{submodule_name}" ("controllers.website").

And this results in an error in Eclipse for each controllers.

How can I fix that in Eclipse? Is it possible to rename the folder? or tell Eclipse it's okay in that case?

Comment: I have renamed my controller package too, just rename it, rename it in routes and `clean, compile, eclipse`

Comment: This is a good answer, not a comment ;) I'll accept it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have renamed my controller package too, just rename it, rename it in routes and run the following commands:

`play clean` and

`play compile` and

`play eclipse`

Read more about this topic: [Play Framework: How to change play default packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816248/play-framework-how-to-change-play-default-packages/9994758#9994758)

Comment: I have simillar problem with submodules models. Could You help me? It is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884772/package-names-namespaces-in-subproject-classes-in-play-framework