# Is it possible to have a route from a sub project used in a template in the main project in Play?

Tags: module, playframework, playframework-2.1, subproject

I have a Play (2.1.2) project that contains a submodule "manager".

I'd like to use the router from my submodule in a template located in the main project.

I tried theses :

```
@controllers.manager.routes.MyController.method
@controllers.routes.MyController.method
@controllers.routes.manager.MyController.method
```

Nothing worked.

For information, I followed the tutorial located in the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/SBTSubProjects) :

I have this project structure :

```
app
  └ controllers
  └ models
  └ views
conf
  └ application.conf
  └ routes
modules
  └ manager
    └ conf/manager.routes
    └ app/controllers
    └ app/models
    └ app/views     
project
 └ build.properties
 └ Build.scala
 └ plugins.sbt
```

And in the main routes :

```
->  /admin manager.Routes
```

Only things I did, was to put my routes in manager.routes without the sub package "manager" (controllers.manager) , I directly named them like in the main project (controllers), for [this problem with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520954/playframework-2-1-submodules-and-eclipse-having-errors-about-invalid-package-na). The same goes for the "package" name in my controllers in my subproject.

Is it possible to use the routes of a sub project in the main project ?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it should look like this:

```
@admin.routes.Application.index

@module.routes.MyController.method
```